# Split Video Files and Make them individually playable

Tags: python, sockets, video, ffmpeg, webm

I am newbie to this python. I split webm video file into chunks, but i couldn't able to make them individually playable using python program.But it plays after I join the chunks to a single file. I know its due to the absence of header file. Please help me with the codes to attach the header file to the parts to make them indiviually playable. Please reply. Thanks alot in advance.

Here is the code:

Client side:

```
import socket, os
import time

client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client_socket.connect(("localhost", 5005))
size = 1024

while True:
    fname = "/home/xincoz/test/conn2.webm"
    fn = client_socket.recv(1024)
    print fn

    fp = open(fname,'wb')
    while True:
        strng = client_socket.recv(int(fn))
        print strng
        if not strng:
            break
        fp.write(strng)
    fp.close()

    print "Data Received successfully"
    exit()
```

Server side:

```
import os,kaa.metadata  
import sys,time 
import socket
import Image

server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.bind(("localhost", 5005))
server_socket.listen(5)

client_socket, address = server_socket.accept()
print "Conencted to - ",address,"\n"

file = '/home/xincoz/Downloads/connect.webm'
a = kaa.metadata.parse(file)

print '\n Maybe, pending work'
file_name = open(file,'rb')
size=str(os.path.getsize(file))
print size
client_socket.send(str(os.path.getsize(file)))
print file_name
strng = file_name.read(os.path.getsize(file))
client_socket.send(strng[0:2000000])
file_name.close()

print str(a)+"Meta Data"
print "Data sent successfully"
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please post some code examples so that we can see what you've already tried.

Comment: also format your code please. its unreadable.

Comment: You tagged your question with both Python 2.7 and Python 3.x. I really doubt that your code runs under both. **Which** are you using?

Comment: It worked on Python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

I am not too familiar with the .webm format, but if is anything like an .avi file I doubt cutting the data off incomplete and saving it to a file will be enough. I assume [0:2000000] is where you are limiting the size? If it is like an .avi then your file should be split properly using tools like ffmpeg or mencoder on the server, then send the full outputted file to the client instead of cutting the data off prematurely.